# Textual find and replace within an XML column

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql, replace

I'm trying to find and replace all instances of 'this phrase' with 'that phrase' in an xml type column using T-SQL.

The xml column contains fields that are more than 8000 characters long.

I tried using the `Replace` function but it doesn't like the XML data type, and the data can't be squeezed into a varchar.

Comment: How many rows are we talking about?  More than 1 or two?

Comment: @AllenG: Around 20 rows or so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever size it is, it can be put in a `varchar(max)` (a datatype new with 2005), which supports all the text-manipulation functions.

Answer (score 1):

I've never done it myself, but it looks like [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345117(SQL.90).aspx) should help.  It looks like you'll do an Update statement like:

```
UPDATE [Table]
SET Document.Modify('[namespace declaration];
    Replace Value Of [Xpath expression] with [New Value]')
```

But I would definately read that article carefully- just skimming it, I may have missed something.